# Can Google Sign-in be used with Touch ID

Tags: iphone, google-signin, touch-id

Can Google Sign-In be used on an iPhone app in conjunction with Touch ID? If so, how? I cannot find any examples of this being done or talked about online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps can incorporate TouchID as a means to *locally* authenticate a user.

Basically, the TouchID system can be queried and will let you access items in a keychain or do a simple one-off authentication.

If you stored Google account credentials in a local keychain, you could use TouchID to unlock the local keychain item, and then pass that item to a Google service for Google's authentication.

The keychain item in question (a password) would have to be enter manually at least once by the user (and at that point, it is probably more straightforward to just request an reusable authentication token from Google).

TouchID is entirely a local system, no fingerprint data is ever exposed to third party developers or pushed to a network, so Google couldn't store a fingerprint in their servers and allow direct authentication against their services using TouchID.

---

Here's the framework reference for Local Authentication:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html

The Local Authentication framework is best suited for either confirming a logged in user in an app where the user may be logged in between many sessions (such as for a purchase in a shopping app) or local authentication for local documents (such as for password protected note taking apps).